# Regarding anytime in English

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, spoken-english

**Question**: Can I come to your office day after tomorrow?
**Answer1**: You can come at anytime.
**Answer2**: You can come at anyday.

Which one of the above answer is correct?

Comment: The first one is correct and the second one isn't. However, if you want any more guidance than that (at least from me), you'll have to expand your question a bit. You asked a question with a "which one" question, and I told you which one.

Comment: thanks for your response, can you please tell me, when to use ‘anytime’ and ‘anyday’. are they one and the same in terms since they represent time or different?

Comment: "Any day" is always two words.  "Anytime" is sometimes a single word (more often in AmE than in BrE), but only as an adverb.  "Any time" as a noun phrase (and hence "at any time") should be always be written with spaces.

Comment: can we use, ‘at any day’ instead of ‘at any time’ to answer the question i asked initially? i feel they look similar for me sometime since they are times

Comment: No, you can't say "at any day", because we don't say "at (a) day" in English.  We use *on* to refer to days, so you could say "on any day".

Answer (score -1):

*Anyday* is not a word - it's always *any day*, two separate words.

*Any day* means whatever day you or someone/something else wants.  It might also mean any *time* if a time hasn't been established, but if one has it does not alter it.

> A: Can you come over at noon during my lunch today?
>
> B: I can't make it today.  Which day after today is good for you?
>
> A: Any day.
>
> B: Ok, cool. (B expects A to arrive at noon on whichever day A chooses)

Also, *any day* is not a time expression and doesn't need *at* (*on* would be more correct but also optional).  *At* is optional with *anytime*.

E.g.

> I want to come over at 3pm. (*at* not optional).
>
> I want to come over [at] anytime you want.
>
> I want to come over anytime you want.
>
> I want to come over [on] Tuesday.
>
> I want to come over [on] any day.

Comment: anytime https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anytime is an adverb and should not be used with a prepostion [at]. any time is either adverb or determiner + noun and so a preposition [at] is optional. any day is determiner + noun and so a preposition is required [on].